# When is a data bound control updated?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to display the results of a complicated SQL query in a series of panels on a form.  I can see how to do this using an `Sqlconnection` and reading the results to a `datatable`, then looping though to create my display.

However the database will be updated by other users elsewhere, so my display will get out of date. How can I tell if the results of the SQL query have changed without continuously running the query?

Comment: Have you looked into Query Notifications?

Comment: Thanks, I set up query notifications which looked like a great solution.  However it wasn't compatible with our ERP system, which effectively owns the database.  The whole thing stopped working.  I set up a query to update every 10 seconds instead.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a great solution - you could be placing a large performance hit on the server that may cause the overall system performance to suffer. For example if your query transverses little used, large tables, you will be consuming SQL Server cache better used by other parts of the system. If there is a human looking at your data I question the need for "near real time" data. Wouldn't a refresh button work as well?

Comment: @rheitzman You're right. However the display shows factory attendance on a screen on the wall, people walk by and look at it so a refresh button isn't ideal.
The IT admins aren't happy with me experimenting more with Query Notifications since I took out the system before, but I might try again when everyone is on holiday...